# Jupyter Notebook chrome webdriver path

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, jupyter

Why does this code not work? I just downloaded the chromedriver and saved it in C... I copy as path in insert
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
import random

driver = webdriver.chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

Output:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

> driver = webdriver.chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

`webdriver.chrome` is treated as a sub package/module, since it's not an existing function and you list it under the `webdriver` module -- and you're trying to call that module.

You meant to type:

```py
# note the capital "C" in Chrome, it's not "chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: thank you. I insert you example and got this error:

Comment: C:\Users\Lisa\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18436\2398135420.py:1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\envs\main\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py:71, in Service.start(self)
     70     cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
---> 71     self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
     72                                     close_fds=system() != 'Windows',
     73                                     stdout=self.log_file,
     74                                     stderr=self.log_file,

Comment: replace "C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" with the exact path your chromedriver.exe lies in

Comment: and put an r before the string to treat it as a raw string, without the backslashes leading to any unintended escapes e.g r"path/to/exe"

Answer (score 0):

Windows' paths should be either written with *two backslashes* or *be prefixed with `r`*.

Try prefixing your selenium initialization below with the `r`, as shown below:

```
driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked just fine driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

I just changed the folder to where I have placed the chromedriver.exe

Also, you can use the tester versions of Chrome and Chromedriver from this link below so they never update or break.

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

We all hate when Chrome updates and then the Chromedriver is broke.

simply download the latest Chrome version delete the files under your Chrome install folder and paste the downloaded version into the proper folder.

WHY do this?

This way Chrome will not update and cause you problems.

Enjoy